# How do I make a count down timer to run alongside my game in python?

Tags: python, timer, countdown

I'm fairly new to Python and have created a trivia quiz, linking to txt files for the questions / answers and to store the high scores.

**EDIT** I AM NOT USING PYGAME

I would like to set a time limit for the questions to be answered, for example 1 minute. I've managed to get the timer to countdown but it counts down and then proceeds to my game.

Is there a way to make it run alongside? I thought about a while loop but it just messed it up so I'm guessing I did it wrong...

Here's my code (well the top bit):

```
import linecache
import sys
import pickle
import time

def countdown():
    t = 60
    while t:
        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
        timeformat = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timeformat, end='\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1
    print('You're out of time!\n')

def travel():
    i = 0
    countdown()
    name = input("What is your name: ")
    q1 = linecache.getline("travel.txt", 1)
    a1 = linecache.getline("travel.txt", 2)
    b1 = linecache.getline("travel.txt", 3)
    c1 = linecache.getline("travel.txt", 4)
    print("\n", q1, a1, b1, c1)
    q = input("Answer: ")
    if q == "b":
        print("Correct! You've scored 1 point.")
        i += 1
    else:
        print("Wrong answer buddy, 0 points.")
```

Comment: You could use the `Thread` module

Comment: how does that work?

Comment: I think it runs a procedure in the background, but I''m not so sure. Haven't used it much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Game Timer (Threads?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325277/python-game-timer-threads)

Comment: @agtoever no, as OP is not using pygame

Comment: @AJ123 the OP should do that. Why reinvent the wheel? PyGame provides a valid and sensible solution to the OP’s problem, as the accepted answer shows...

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to, you could use `threading.Thread` to have this functionality.

Note the following code:

```
import threading
import time     

def countdown():
    t = 60
    while t:
        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
        timeformat = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timeformat, end='\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1
    print("You're out of time!\n")
    # add some function which stops the game, for example by changing a variable to false (which the main thread always checks) 
    # or some other method like by checking count_thread.is_alive()

def main_game():
    count_thread = threading.Thread(None, countdown)
    # do game things
```

In this example, the `print("You're out of time")` will happen 60 seconds after `main_game()` is started, but at the same time the code at `# do game things` will be run. All you need to implement is a way for either the count_thread itself to kill the game, or make the game check whether the thread is still alive, and if not, to exit.